# Ordering VARCHAR field that consist of dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with a VARCHAR field that stores the dates in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`. This table already have data stored in it, and I am required to sort this data in a descending order. Is this possible?

Comment: make datatype to date for the coloumn this is not  good approach to store date as a string in mysql

Comment: Why do so many people store dates incorrectly?

Comment: @MartinSmith Sometimes it is inherited, other times it is people just starting out and learning. We can but try to teach them to use proper dates :)

Comment: So @dianuj it wouldnt do anything to the data if I just convert the data type?

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande yes. Once you got date stored in filed of correct type, mysql will know what it mean and how to sort it correctly. Then you just do `ORDER my_date_field DESC` and that's it. So fix your database and do not add any workarounds like this you asked about

Comment: no if you convert datatype to date while having data in coloumn it will be lost

Comment: Does the way you store your date matters, ie. 21-Jan-09, of 21 January 2009?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to deal with dates is to store then as a date data type.

You can easily convert the data that is in them now into a date column by adding a column of date datatype, merging the data into it and then re-naming it.

```sql
alter  yourTable add dateColumnName date;
update yourTable set dateColumnName = STR_TO_DATE(oldDateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y');
drop column oldDateColumn;
alter table yourTable change dateColumnName oldDateColumn date;
```

If you do this, you will be able to do all sorts of complex date stuff (not limited to just sorting a date nicely, or getting the data out in different formats - but calculations, comparisons and much more). You will need to be aware that you will also have to probably change how you insert data into the column - though there are many easy ways to convert a string-date from a CSV or form into a proper date column.

**Edit**: As Martin points out, if you have some bum data stored in there now, it might cause problems when converting to a date, but you can find these reasonably easily when doing the update. After the *update...* query is run, simply run the following:

```
select count(*) from yourTable where dateColumnName is null; // Total Problem Count
select * from yourTable where dateColumnName is null; // Detail
```

This will show you the rows that didn't update

Comment: +1 Of course assumes the OP doesn't already have invalid dates in their data which is always a possibility when storing as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert that string value to a proper date for sorting:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Something like:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_column, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it with the str_to_date mysql function 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Not tested but it should be something like

```
select * from table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,"%e-%c-%Y");
```